# check_output error in Python when trying to list folders in a path

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a code which displays the file format of a particular path.

But I'm getting the following error, related to the path specified. The file which is executing in 'C:\Research\LungCancerDetaction\Preprocessing2.py' folder.

The 'input' folder is in path, C:\Research\input.

The following is the code written.

```
    import numpy as np # Linear algebra
    import pandas as pd # Data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
    import skimage, os
    from skimage.morphology import ball, disk, dilation, binary_erosion, remove_small_objects, erosion, closing, reconstruction, binary_closing
    from skimage.measure import label,regionprops, perimeter
    from skimage.morphology import binary_dilation, binary_opening
    from skimage.filters import roberts, sobel
    from skimage import measure, feature
    from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
    from skimage import data
    from scipy import ndimage as ndi
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
    import dicom
    import scipy.misc
    import numpy as np

    # Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
    # For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list the files in the input directory

    import subprocess
    print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

But I'm getting the error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Research/LungCancerDetaction/Preprocessing2.py", line 22, in <module>
        print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\subprocess.py", line 693, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How do I figure out the error?

Comment: Why do you need so many imports to execute a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line...

`print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))`

... and use this instead:

```
import os

print(os.listdir('../input'))
```